# React Exhaustive Deps with useCallback

Tags: reactjs

I know this is a very common problem but I can't quite wrap my brain around how to handle it.

I have a settings page that loads the settings from an electron store. I keep the settings in a state. So it is best to assume that `window.settings` is an API that allows me to bridge across into the electron side of things.

My trouble comes when I want to sync the settings from the API.

I am using `useEffect` to initially fetch the values for the `settings` state. Then when the state is changed, I use a function to set them via API. So hopefully, the `useEffect` should only run once or at most twice depending on if `window` is available.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import FloatingLabel from 'react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel'

const Settings = () => {

  const defaultSettings = {
    alwaysOnTop: false,
    popOnOutbound: false
  }

  const [settings, setSettings] = useState(defaultSettings)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window !== undefined && window.settings !== undefined) {
      Object.keys(defaultSettings).forEach((key) => {
        window.settings.get(key).then((value) => {
          if (value !== undefined) {
            setSettings() // Here is the problem. I want to update just the particular key in settings, but without `settings` I can't correctly update the object.
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }, [window.settings, setSettings, defaultSettings]) //Notice settings is not a dependency.

  const handleFieldChange = (field, value) => {
    const newSettings = { ...settings }
    newSettings[field] = value
    setSettings(newSettings)
    if (window !== undefined && window.settings !== undefined) {
      window.settings.set(field, value)
    }
  }



  return(
    <div className="p-3 text-start">
      <div className="mb-3">
        <Form.Check
          type="switch"
          id="alwaysOnTop"
          label="Always on top"
          onChange={(e) => { handleFieldChange('alwaysOnTop', e.target.checked) }}
          checked={settings.alwaysOnTop}
        />
        <small className="text-muted">Whether the app is pinned above all other screens.</small>
      </div>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <Form.Check
          type="switch"
          id="popOnInbound"
          label="Pop on inbound"
          onChange={(e) => { handleFieldChange('popOnInbound', e.target.checked) }}
          checked={settings.popOnInbound}
        />
        <small className="text-muted">Whether the app pops up when an inbound call is received.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Settings
```

The simple fix would just be to not include `settings` as a dep and everything works fine but it raises the linter error and I know I'm not doing things the right way.

I could possibly fetch all settings from the API and update them all, that way I can just `setSettings(newSettingsFromApi)`, but that runs the risk of the server and client being out of sync and the settings from the API overriding the local changes before they are persisted.

What would you do given the above?

Comment: One way i can think of is to move the state settings in the parent component, or better in the root component of this app and then pass the setter to Setting component and do what you’re doing in the exact way,  because when you do that, you get rid of updating the state of the same component where your useEffect is there. And that helps you get rid of re renders.

Comment: I don't have an issue with re-renders, it is just the linter complaining that `settings` is used in the `useEffect` hook but not declared as a dependancy.

Comment: You can’t get rid of it. Its the only way. This will give you some more insights https://youtu.be/HPoC-k7Rxwo